# What is the opposite of "Expiring Soon"?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of "Expiring Soon". I want to sort a list based on these two options based on the expiry date.

For example, say you've rented some films on your set top box and you're looking at the list of them. I want to show the options:

> Sort by
>
> - expiring soon
> - expiring ???

Comment: The true opposite is "lasting forever".

Comment: Can't you just say "expiration date ascending" and "expiration date descending"?

Comment: To figure out the best term, I think you should examine your use-case. Why would a user want to see the items whose expiration-dates are furthest in the future? What are they really looking for? Once you know that, you can come up with an intuitive name that will make sense to the user who needs it.

Comment: for example, take the use case where you have some rented videos in you STB. The user wants to arrange the list based on this.

Comment: STB? Strange Tabernacle Box?

Comment: SetTopBOX .. :-p

Comment: Not every phrase has an exact opposite.

Comment: "expiring soon" and "not expiring soon"

Comment: @ruakh: "Why would a user want to see the". Becuase user wants to see videos that will expire soon at the bottom of the list. Your advice is bad from programmers perspective. "Sort direction" is very cheap to implement, also this feature present in nearly all software, so there's no need for "examining use-case".

Comment: @SigTerm: Well, I *am* a programmer. (And in the VOD space, just as Sen seems to be.) You're entitled to your own opinion, but you certainly don't speak for all programmers when you think my advice is bad. This feature may be cheap to implement, but it takes up screen real estate, adds clutter, and imposes a cognitive load on the user. It also adds a set of test-cases that will need to be performed every time this set of features needs to be re-tested for whatever reason (e.g., support for a new Back Office). So I think he should only add this if he thinks that someone might actually use it.

Comment: @ruakh: *"but it takes up screen real estate"* Most likely it doesn't, because table column header most likely already present and is narrower than table content. *"It also adds a set of test-cases"* It seems that you're overusing unit-testing. Using unit-tests for every trivial scenario is a bad idea, because it will increase workload without providing benefits. Also, decent GUI toolkit will provide this functionality for free, so you'll only need to enable it. *"cognitive load"* If that feature adds too much of cognitive load to your user, then he/she won't be able to use your app anyway.

Comment: @SigTerm: I take it you haven't read my comment to your answer?

Comment: why dont you keep one just called valid until.
then it can be sorted by date

Comment: The opposite of _expires soon_ is (also) ***just expired***.

Answer (score 9):

For your example of sorting a user interface, I would use superlatives:

- expiring soonest
- expiring latest

It's difficult to find an opposite for *soon* that is useful because it's not specific enough. Using superlatives, in this case, tell us that we're looking at the dates in question, not some subjective notion of what *soon* means.

Comment: Or "expiring sooner", "expiring later"

Answer (score 3):

"Sort by: Expiring soon" sounds like a Boolean. I think that to express what you actually want to do you should look at terms like

> Sort by:
>
> - Expiring soonest first
> - Expiring latest first

Comment: I agree with this in principle, but I'd probably write it out as "Sort by: Expiration (soonest first)".

Answer (score 1):

> Sort by

"Sort by expiration date".

> I want to show the options: Sort by expiring soon

I'd say this is a bad gui design.

Put data into table (multi-column), add header to the table, allow user to sort data by clicking column's header, indicate sort direction using arrows or unicode "triangle" symbol (pointing up/down). This is a fairly standard behavior.

Comment: That's a fairly standard behavior on web-pages (which a user typically interacts with via a mouse), but I don't think it's very common in STB applications (which a user typically interacts with via a remote control). STB applications are getting richer every year, and your advice will probably be good advice someday (assuming digital cable is still around by then), but right now I'm not sure it's really practical.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your use case, a user interface, I would have a  input titled "Expires", and offer two sort options: "Sooner", and "Later".

Answer (score 1):

In the case of food items, "shelf-stable" and "perishable" are the two relevant antonyms.

If you're categorizing stuff for storage, you might be more quantitative, and call your categories "expiring within 7 days" and "expiry 8 days or beyond", adjusting the numbers to suit your purpose. Never mind how you phrase the category names, "soon" is going to be ambiguous.